# Getting the indexes of each element in a list of lists and making a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am trying to create a dictionary where the keys are elements of each list, and the values are their indexes in that list of lists, so that I can easily find where exactly every element is.

So if the list is `[['a', 'a', 'b'], ['a', 'b', 'b'], ['c', 'c', 'c']]` ,

dictionary should be like this:`{'c': {(2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)}, 'b': {(1, 1), (1, 2), (0, 2)}, 'a': {(0, 1), (1, 0), (0, 0)}}`

I can get each elements index in their respective lists with list comprehension: `final_list = [list(enumerate(i)) for i in mylist]` but I couldn't find a way to get their "complete" indexes that also include the index of their list.

Comment: Have you tried any solutions without list comprehension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple solution:

```
input = [['a', 'a', 'b'], ['a', 'b', 'b'], ['c', 'c', 'c']]

result = {}
for i, lst in enumerate(input):
    for j, element in enumerate(lst):
        if element in result:
            result[element].add((i, j))
        else:
            result[element] = {(i, j)}
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Fyi, `{}` creates `dict` and for `set` we can use `set()`. +1

Comment: You're welcome @zipa, I like your answer more than mine, you deserved the +1 for the idea :)

Answer (score 3):

you can use:

```
l = [['a', 'a', 'b'], ['a', 'b', 'b'], ['c', 'c', 'c']]

result = {}
for i, e in enumerate(l):
    for j, x in enumerate(e):
        result.setdefault(x, set()).add((i, j))
print(result)
```

output:

```
{'a': {(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0)},
 'b': {(0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2)},
 'c': {(2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
res = {}
for i, l in enumerate(var):
    for j, letter in enumerate(l):
        res[letter] = res.get(letter, set()) | {(i, j)}

res

# {'a': {(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0)},
#  'b': {(0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2)},
#  'c': {(2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)}}
```

Answer (score 2):

While it would be very inefficient to write a one-liner, you can use `collections.defaultdict` to simplify things. It's actually nicer that using `dict.setdefault` because it doesn't create an empty container every time you want to append a value, even when the key is already present:

```
result = defaultdict(list)
for i, row in enumerate(mylist):
     for j, key in enumerate(row):
         result[key].append((i, j))
```

A one line solution would have to make multiple passes over `mylist` to accumulate all the values for a given key. This would be needlessly complicated and run with O(n^2) time complexity.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation

Comment: @arthionne. Glad you liked it.

Comment: Good solution, did somebody ask for a one-liner because I don't see it mentioned in the question

Comment: @jamylak. I thought OP wanted a single comprehension, but I confused it with another question.

Comment: How come dict.setdefault creates a container every time you want to append a value? You can check the docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault

Comment: @kederrac the statement `result.setdefault(x, set())` first calls `set()` no matter whether `x in result` or not. The call to `set` is made before the call to `setdefault`. By delegating container creation to the dictionary itself, you avoid this (incredibly minor) overhead.